# How to install MyEclipse Properties Editor in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have used MyEclipse for a long time and now I am changed to eclipse,I want to install MyEclipse Properties Editor in Eclipse。

But when I search the Internet,most of the recommended result is to install [Properties Editor](http://propedit.sourceforge.jp/index_en.html),however I do not like this style and skin of this plugin,what I like is the **MyEclipse Properties Editor** and I want to install it in Eclipse,but I do not found a way to do it,can anybody help me,please? Thanks in advance!

Pictures for **MyEclipse Properties Editor** looks like:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The MyEclipse Property Editor is not a separately installable part of MyEclipse. If it were possible to install it separately (which it isn't), you'd still need a MyEclipse license to use it.